# Is the following a correct use of "which in itself?"

Tags: sentence, phrase-usage

> The tree was thick and tall as a watch tower. Its branches resembled twisted arms,
>   and they had so few leaves you could count them with your fingers.
>   Like some kind of parasites, moss covered almost the totality of its
>   surface—**which in itself** was filled with curves, holes, and other
>   deformities.

I'm not sure why I placed it there. At first I only wrote *which*, but I felt something was missing.

Answer (score 1):

I would simplify the sentence to insure the reader understands the curves and holes refer to the surface and not the moss:

*Like some kind of parasite, moss covered the totality of its surface--a surface filled with curves, holes, and other deformities.*

Note the singular for *parasite.*

Comment: I see. I guess repetition is useful sometimes.

Comment: I like your writing style.  Since I am only a Student and not an Editor, feel free to ignore my comments